# Arduino nano stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1

Tags: arduino-nano, avrdude, ch340, usbasp

I have been building a project using an arduino nano clone. It uses the CH340 chip. It worked perfectly, and a week later it now doesnt.

When I want to upload code in arduino IDE I get the error below

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
```

To try to fix the issue, I bought a USBasp board to program the nano, however, when I run AVRdude, it reads

```
avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
     Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
     this check.}
```

If anyone can help please do

Thanks